# overloading functions of the fp package

Tags: calculations, etoolbox, fp

I have a document with several commands that store numeric variables inside an extra macro.  This extra macro will highlight that text so I can track them in the printed document.  Like so:

```
\newcommand{\ScriptValue}[1]{\colorbox[gray]{0.8}{#1}}

\newcommand{\HTwoA}{\ScriptValue{10.3}}
\newcommand{\HTwoB}{\ScriptValue{11.3}}
\newcommand{\HTwoC}{\ScriptValue{10.7}}
```

I make extensive use of them in the text and use the `fp` and `intcalc` packages to compute new values.  Those newly computed values should continue to be automatically highlighted with `\ScriptValue`.

In order to do this, I renew the commands from the fp package to a version where `\ScriptValue` is locally set to an empty macro.  This was very much based in [an answer from here too](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/159220/24374). Like so:

```
\documentclass[article,draft]{memoir}

\usepackage{color}
\usepackage{fp}

\newcommand{\ScriptValue}[1]{\colorbox[gray]{0.8}{#1}}
\let\RealScriptValue\ScriptValue

\newcommand{\HTwoA}{\ScriptValue{10.3}}
\newcommand{\HTwoB}{\ScriptValue{11.3}}
\newcommand{\HTwoC}{\ScriptValue{10.7}}

\let\RealFPmin\FPmin
\renewcommand{\FPmin}[3]{%
  \renewcommand{\ScriptValue}[1]{##1}%
  \RealFPmin{\UnmarkedResult}{#2}{#3}%
  \renewcommand{\ScriptValue}{\RealScriptValue}%
  \FPset{#1}{\ScriptValue{\UnmarkedResult}}%
}

\FPmin{\HTwoAB}{\HTwoA}{\HTwoB}

\begin{document}
  Min of A and B is \HTwoAB{}
\end{document}
```

Until this point, it works fine. However, I am having issues when I want to use those newly computed values in the overloaded macros one more time.  For example, with the above overload of `\FPmin` the following fails:

```
\FPmin{\result}{\HTwoA}{\HTwoB}
\FPmin{\HMinAll}{\result}{\HTwoC}
```

This is certainly due to me messing up the overloading since it all works fine if there is no `\ScriptValue` in the first place.  The following would work perfectly:

```
\documentclass[article,draft]{memoir}

\usepackage{fp}

\newcommand{\HTwoA}{10.3}
\newcommand{\HTwoB}{11.3}
\newcommand{\HTwoC}{10.7}

\FPmin{\result}{\HTwoA}{\HTwoB}
\FPmin{\HMinAll}{\result}{\HTwoC}

\begin{document}
  Min of all is \HMinAll{}
\end{document}
```

I believe my issue to be at the line where I call `\FPset`.  I have tried multiple different things with `let`s, and `expandafter`s, and `defs`s, and `csedef`s, but still got nothing that worked reliably.

How can this be done correctly? I want this to work "invisibly". The point is for other people working on the document with me, to not worry with `\ScriptValue`. To have things just working for them as if they were dealing with "just" numeric variables when they call the functions from `fp` and `intcalc`.

For what is worth, I am already using the `etoolbox` if that makes the problem simpler.

Comment: I think you're better avoiding such tricks. Using `\ScriptValue{\HMinAll}` when you need the box seems much better and frees you from these complications.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You were never restoring the definition (there was no local scope around the `\renewcommand`. this seems to do what you want:

```
\documentclass[article,draft]{memoir}

\usepackage{color}
\usepackage{fp}

\newcommand{\ScriptValue}[1]{\colorbox[gray]{0.8}{#1}}
\let\RealScriptValue\ScriptValue

\newcommand{\HTwoA}{\ScriptValue{10.3}}
\newcommand{\HTwoB}{\ScriptValue{11.3}}
\newcommand{\HTwoC}{\ScriptValue{10.7}}

\let\RealFPmin\FPmin
\renewcommand{\FPmin}[3]{%
  \renewcommand{\ScriptValue}[1]{##1}%
  \RealFPmin{\UnmarkedResult}{#2}{#3}%
  \edef#1{\noexpand\ScriptValue{\UnmarkedResult}}%
  \let\ScriptValue\RealScriptValue
}

\FPmin{\HTwoAB}{\HTwoA}{\HTwoB}

\FPmin{\result}{\HTwoA}{\HTwoB}
\FPmin{\HMinAll}{\result}{\HTwoC}

\begin{document}
  Min of A and B is \HTwoAB{}

  Min of A and B is \HMinAll{}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1):

Not really an answer, but an advice: you're probably trying to overload `fp` commands because they're clumsy and difficult to manage. Here's a better interface.

```
\documentclass[article,draft]{memoir}

\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{xparse}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\NewDocumentCommand{\printvalue}{m}
 {
  \colorbox[gray]{0.8}{ \fp_eval:n { #1 } }
 }
\ExplSyntaxOff

\newcommand{\HTwoA}{10.3}
\newcommand{\HTwoB}{11.3}
\newcommand{\HTwoC}{10.7}

\begin{document}
Min of A and B is \printvalue{ min(10.3,11.3) }

Max of A and C is \printvalue{ max(\HTwoA,\HTwoC) }
\end{document}
```

The floating point module of `expl3` features a very natural syntax and supports much more function than the old `fp` package.

[image]

Comment: (+1) for 'they're clumsy and difficult to manage'.