# Redefine existing commands outside preamble

Tags: automation, preamble, makefile

I have a Latex document where a lot of the text and figures is
generated automatically by a program.  In a minimal example, the final
document is like this:

```
\documentclass{memoir}

%% This file is generated automatically, and is full of
%% \newcommand definitions
\input{variables}

\begin{document}
  \input{text} % makes heavy use of commands defined in variables.tex
\end{document}
```

The program that generates the `variables.tex` file has multiple
options which change the return value of the Latex commands it
defines.  This means that I can always use the same document as
structure but control the actual content from `variables.tex`.

Now I want to have `text.tex` twice in the same document, each time
using a `variables-X.tex` file built with different options.  However,
they both define different commands with the same name.

I would go about doing this? In my mind would be something like:

```
\documentclass{memoir}
\begin{document}

  \input{variables-1}
  \input{text}

  \input{variables-2}
  \input{text}

\end{document}
```

But that fails with "Command \SequencesDate already defined." (this is one of the commands defined inside `variables.tex`). If instead of `\newcommand` I use `\renewcommand`, I get a "\SequencesDate undefined" error.

My actual case is a bit more complicated. I hope this doesn't add extra noise to the question but I guess it may have some impact on what can be done.  The commands defined in the `variables.tex` are mainly numeric with a grey background. But these commands are still used in operations involving the `fp` package and that is done by redefining the command that controls the background.  Like this:

### File `variables.tex`

```
\newcommand{\Foo}{\ScriptValue{5.3}}
\newcommand{\Bar}{\ScriptValue{5.6}}
```

### File `text.tex`

```
\FPmin{\MinFooBar}{\Foo}{\Bar}
The smallest foobar is \MinFooBar
```

### File `document.tex`

```
\documentclass{memoir}
\usepackage{color}
\usepackage{fp}

\input{variables}

%% Color automatic values with grey background
\newcommand{\ScriptValue}[1]{\setlength{\fboxsep}{0pt}\colorbox[gray]{0.8}{\strut #1}}

%% We also want to make operations with those values in LaTeX
%% using FPeval but FPeval fails because ScriptValue gets expanded into
%% something non-numeric.  So we use the following trick: we store the
%% original ScriptValue and FPeval macros, and then replace FPeval with
%% something that temporarily disables ScriptValue while we call the
%% original FPeval.
%% See https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/159155/identify-pieces-of-text-automatically-generated-from-input-and-new-command
%% and https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/283655/overloading-functions-of-the-fp-package

\let\RealScriptValue\ScriptValue

\let\RealFPmin\FPmin
\renewcommand{\FPmin}[3]{%
  \renewcommand{\ScriptValue}[1]{##1}%
  \RealFPmin{\UnmarkedResult}{#2}{#3}%
  \edef#1{\noexpand\ScriptValue{\UnmarkedResult}}%
  \renewcommand{\ScriptValue}{\RealScriptValue}%
}


\begin{document}
  \input{text}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Well... this depends on the way you have defined you commands, I would say. If they are all `\def` , a `{\input...}` group would be sufficient

Comment: well if you do what you suggest did it work? If it did, what is the question? If it did not, what error did you get?

Comment: Assuming you have `\newcommand` statements, say for `\foo` and `\foobar` you could use `\let\foo\relax` and `\let\foobar\relax` at the top of your `variables.tex` file. Since you're generating this file automatically, it should be easy to let your generator do this for you

Comment: The new commands are defined with `\newcommand`.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle I added the actual error message as well as more details on my actual case.

Comment: @carandraug actually I'd have gone with Christian's first suggestion of a group rather than undefining everything with `\relax` but whatever works:-)

Comment: @DavidCarlisle: Grouping has no effect for `\newcommand`, as far as I know

Comment: @ChristianHupfer of course it does, it's just `\def` really.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle: I tried grouping and it complained about that `\foo` already exists.

Comment: well it must already have existed in that case.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle: We're talking of different setups. Of course, if `{\newcommand{\foo}{...}}` will be safe. I was thinking about of a first occurence of `\input{variables}` where the macros where defined already, in a further usage `{\input{variables}}` would fail.

Comment: @ChristianHupfer if that were the case the original use shown by the OP with a single input would already fail

Comment: @DavidCarlisle: I was thinking of the usage in the body, not in the preamble

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let your 'variables.tex' - generator do a loop and say for each of the defined commands `\foo` etc. `\let\foo\relax` etc.

This way it is undefined at the top of each input of the `variables.tex` 
Another way: Use `\undef{\foo}` or `\csundef{foo}` from `etoolbox` package.

variables.tex

```
\let\foo\relax
\let\foobar\relax
\newcommand{\foo}{Foo}
\newcommand{\foobar}{Foobar}
```

Driver

```
\documentclass{memoir}

%% This file is generated automatically, and is full of
%% \newcommand definitions

\begin{document}

  \input{variables}

  \input{text} % makes heavy use of commands defined in variables.tex


  \input{variables}% It will do here too with the same file 

  \input{text} % makes heavy use of commands defined in variables.tex

\end{document}
```

text.tex

```
\foo\ and \foobar\ are nice commands
```

**Update**

Another approach without tedious `\let\foo\relax` statements:

Use

```
\begingroup
\input{variables-1}
\input{text}
\endgroup
```

for each of the relevant cases. In this case, there must not be any occurence of `\input{variables}` etc. before!

\input

Comment: My real case was a bit more convoluted with delayed macro expansions all over the place. Your answer seems to still do the job. Thank you.

Comment: @carandraug: See the possible easier way at the end of my answer

Comment: I have tried the alternative (groups) and seems to work fine as well.